# Mathematical-Physics

Tags: discussion, support

There's difference mathematical-physics between theoretical physics as we know. Here are my questions:

- Is this question in mathematical-physics?
- How do we  differenciate between theoretical-physics and mathematical-physics?
- [A Problem on Schrödinger's Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475187/a-problem-on-schr%C3%B6dingers-equation)

When we post our physics question which is involving by mathematical calcuation, 
will it be overlooked? or will it be answered?

See: [How do we find force $F(r)$? (Wave Function)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476680/how-do-we-find-force-fr-wave-function)

Regards!

Comment: Does it matter, how we distinguish theoretical- from mathematical-physics? Are you just asking how to know what tags to put on a question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson There's physics.se for theoretical-physics. So, I'm thinking to post my mathematical-physics questions here. Was my question involving mathematical-physics?

Comment: That's too far from anything I know much about for me to offer an informed opinion.

Comment: @Maxwell Can you explicit your standpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How do we differenciate between theoretical-physics and mathematical-physics?** Mathematical-physics is an area of mathematics. Then problems related to it should be posted on Math.SE. If it is related to *how a physical concept is related/comming from the  mathematical theory* then should be in Physics.SE.

Questions that are related with physics are welcome in Math.SE. They have tags like physics, quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, etc. usually for solving *mathematical problems* that arise when we are dealing with physics questions. These type's of questions will not be welcome in Physics.SE. The Physics.SE community is more reluctant to answer questions that deals only with mathematics of problems, or in how you approach your homework or in general calculations in some result.

If you want to ask a question here you should *see the policy of how to ask a question.* If it deals with concepts of physics the question is *off-topic* and should migrate or be deleted. If the question is asking about the mathematics part of the theory it may be well received.

---

**Is this question in mathematical-physics?** Yes. Your question deals with mathematical-physics. If you look standard mathematical physics textbooks will treat these kind of method to solve partial differential equations. There are several equations that are solved using these treatments in physics. To me your tags are correct. The problem is in the text. It is important to set correctly the functions, say what are the domains and etc, say what are all the equations (mathematical experts in partial differential equations do not need to know the time-independent Schroedinger equations), say what are all the constants and what type of function is $V$. This is very important for mathematical-physics and mathematicians, and is something that usually physics don't care a lot.

---

**What is mathematical-physics?** With modern knowledge, mathematical-physics is an area of research within the theoretical physics and mathematics, that is characterized not by studying specific physical systems, like the areas of Mechanics of Thermodynamics, but by presenting a specific approach when dealing with physical problems. More specifically, Mathematical-Physics deals primarily with *mathematical rigor* and *clearness* in theoretical physics, trying to *enrich concepts and set rigor in the mathematics used* by physicists.

Comment: What a great answer! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @Maxwell. Maybe you should wait for critics and comments in my answer before accepting because this is a point of view that can be different then the community. Other users may differ in opinion.

Comment: But thanks anyway :)

Comment: But It seems too nice also true. I think everyone will agree.

Comment: Also how long does it take to get an answer for my question?

Comment: I think it depends. But if you want answers fast there are things you can do. Usually sending your question in e-mail to others or posting in facebook or other sites is a nice way to get attentions. In stack you can offer a bounty for the question. If you want, I can set a bounty for a question of yours just as an example.

Comment: There are also chats in math.SE in order to show questions to other users.

Comment: It'd be great. Can you?

Comment: How do i make an offer for my question?

Comment: What question does you want to offer?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476680/problem-on-wave-function I want to get an answer for this question. So, if you can make an offer It'd be great.

Comment: A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked. There is this [policy here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). I edited your question so that it will go up in the question topics and may be some other user will see it again. Also, you got an answer for that question but it is not the one you were looking for, you can say it in the comments.